# How to remove extra array values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script does this:

- Put UPC into form
- Submit form
- Check to see if the UPC already exists in my database

  - If yes, fetch it from MySQL database
  - If not, fetch it from an external server, add it to MySQL database for future use
- Display results

It works fine, but I'd like the variable to look exactly the same wether it comes from the MySQL cache, or the external server.

When I print it from the server, it looks like this:

Output:

```
[upc] => 066721020215
[pendingUpdates] => 0
[status] => success
[ean] => 0066721020215
[issuerCountryCode] => us
[found] => 1
[description] => Christie - Original Ritz Crackers
[message] => Database entry found
[size] => 225 g
[issuerCountry] => United States
[noCacheAfterUTC] => 2012-08-06T12:23:58
[lastModifiedUTC] => 2009-04-06T01:51:08
```

However, When I print the array from MySQL, it looks like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UPC WHERE `upc` = '$codes[0]'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "<pre>" . print_r($data, true) . "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
[0] => 066721020215
[upc] => 066721020215
[1] => 0
[pendingUpdates] => 0
[2] => success
[status] => success
[3] => 0066721020215
[ean] => 0066721020215
[4] => us
[issuerCountryCode] => us
[5] => 1
[found] => 1
[6] => Christie - Original Ritz Crackers
[description] => Christie - Original Ritz Crackers
[7] => Database entry found
[message] => Database entry found
[8] => 225 g
[size] => 225 g
[9] => United States
[issuerCountry] => United States
[10] => 2012-08-06
[noCacheAfterUTC] => 2012-08-06
[11] => 2009-04-06
[lastModifiedUTC] => 2009-04-06
```

I realize it's more or less a cosmetic difference (and an array twice as big as it needs to be), but how would I go about easily removing the 0,1,2,3,etc identifiers without looping through the array creating and manually creating a new one? Is there a function that would remove the numbered identifiers?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: You can use MYSQL_ASSOC as second parameter of mysql_fetch_array that will return a multidimensional array with keys named after column names. It is advisable to use mysqli extension though. You can use it pretty much the same as mysql_ for the most part. Just replace mysql with mysqli in function names you're calling.

Comment: First I've heard that mysql_ functions are depreciated. Good to know.

I'm now using 

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "db");
$data = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM UPC WHERE `upc` = '$codes[0]'")->fetch_assoc();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` or `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php for more details.

Note that both are discouraged, as they have been replaced by the new(ish) mysqli functions: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

to:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns the data from the db as an associative array - `mysql_fetch_array` returns a mixed array, with both numeric and associative indexes.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php